# Is there a difference in meaning and usage between "what I hear" and "from what I hear"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell me in which situations I use *what I hear* and *from what I hear*? Is there any difference in meaning and usage between them? For example:

> **What I hear** is that a vaccine for Covid-19 will be available soon.
>
> **From what I hear** is that a vaccine for Covid-19 will be available soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"From what I hear is that (...)" is bad grammar, mixing up two structures into a nonfunctional mess. It's either

> What I hear is that a vaccine will be available soon.

or

> From what I hear, a vaccine will be available soon.

or also

> I hear (that) a vaccine will be available soon.

Answer (score 2):

The meanings are the same, but the second is not idiomatic

> From what I hear, a vaccine will be available soon.

It is slightly more concise than “What I hear is that ...” It may also express a slightly greater degree of doubt.